# show sub categories when click on main category and show products when click on sub cat with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i am working on a module where i have main categories in sidebar in ul and i have one drop down for subcategories. the idea is that when i click on any link in main categories it should show the related subcategories in drop down and when i click on sub category it should show the product details below drop down in list view. i did all this but now looking for ajax to do this for me.

i searched for it but mostly i found drop down for both main and sub categories but i do not need drop down for main categories. send me just an example or any link that have this whole thing rest i will do my home work.

all the record is fetch from database three table that are linked through FK.

thanks in advance for any kind of help.

```
  <div id="main-cat">
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>           
    </ul>
 </div>

<div id="sub-cat">
  <select>
     <option></option>
     <option></option>
     <option></option>
  </select>

  <div id="products">
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
    </ul>
```

now what i want to do is when page loads it show ist div with main categories and when i click any main cat it update the drop down of sub cat accordingly with ajax and then when subcat loads and i click any of the sub cat it loads the third div accordingly with ajax.

hope it will help now

Comment: i am asking because i am not good at searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont get it, why use Ajax for a dropdown menu ?

Anyhow here you go

```
<div class="menuHolder" id="menuHolder">
      <script type="text/javascript">
            loadMenu();
      </script>
</div>
```

Ajax function (.js file)

```
function loadMenu( ANY VALUES HERE ) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/ajax.php?page=menu&key="+value,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("menuHolder").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
              /* returns the HTML from the Ajax page into menuHolder div */
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax.php place this in the root of your server

```
$file = $_GET['page'];

if(file_exists('yourpath/ajax/'.$file.'.php')){
    include_once 'yourpath/ajax/'.$file.'.php';
} else {
    print 'File could not be found';
}
```

Ajax file: menu.php, all html will be returned to given container

```
Your code, Values passed with Ajax can be received with $_GET['key']
<div class="menu" id="menu">
      /* code for menu */
</div>
<?
if(isset($_GET['submenu']) { /* if you passed a value for submenu with ajax */
    ?>
    <div class="submenu" id="menu">
        /* code for submenu */
    </div>
    <?
}
?>
 .......
```

As you notice i dont like JQuery very much, i always use plain javascript, hope thats not a problem

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply i will surely use it but do you suggest me any working example that meet my criteria??

Comment: your criteria is to simpel to use ajax as far as i understand what you want to achieve. Just some javascript functions will do just fine. I dont see the need for ajax

Comment: yes but there is something thing you misunderstood as i can see the html you write is not what i need. let me edit my question

Comment: some code is always the way to go when asking a question haha

Comment: now kindly check out my question i edit it for better understanding

Comment: so when you click on main cat. it goes away and sub cat comes in that place. or does subcat dropdown?

Comment: no main cat should not go away it should be there as well sub cat dropdown will appear when main cat click

Comment: thats why i said send me any working example link which follow same critaria as i search alot but found nothing exactly as i am not good at googling :(

Comment: In your menu add to your buttons: onclick="loadMenu() " or onclick="loadSubmen ( id of the page )" and do all the athor work in Ajax.

Comment: I left you a little puzzeling